# Proving Discontinuity using Epsilon Delta for Function

Tags: continuity, epsilon-delta, piecewise-continuity

sorry if this question ends up being a duplicate, but I wasn't able to find a question sufficiently similar on the exchange.

I have a few questions to go through to practice proving functions are discontinuous using the delta epsilon definition of a limit. I am familiar with using delta-epsilon to prove functions are continuous at a point, but not that they are discontinuous in general. In order to help me solve later problems, please provide a full solution to the problem below, explained as clearly as possible. Thank you! The problem is:

Show that the following function is discontinuous for all $c \in \mathbb R$:

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1/x,  & \text{$x \ne 0$} \\
c, & \text{$x = 0$}
\end{cases}$

Comment: What did you try? At least, do you know how to express discontinuity with delta and epsilon?

Comment: My current thought is we assume that $\lvert x \rvert \lt \delta$ for all $\epsilon$ and then find a $\epsilon$ such that $\lvert 1/x-c \rvert \lt \epsilon$ doesn't hold. I am just a little foggy about how to go about doing that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a *hint* which you can play around with to aid your understanding:

Let $\delta > 0$. Notice that if you choose $x$ such that $0 < |x| < \min\left(\delta, \frac{1}{|c|+1}\right)$ then

$$
|f(x) - c| = \left|\frac{1}{x} - c \right| = \left|\frac{1-cx}{x} \right| \geq \frac{1 - \frac{|c|}{|c|+1}}{\frac{1}{|c|+1}} = 1
$$

Comment: Oh ok, I think I understand, so now if we choose $\epsilon = 1/2$, our delta epsilon definition for continuity doesn't hold.

Comment: Bingo! Or any $\epsilon <1$.

Comment: When it comes to doing questions like this in general, however, what sort of reasoning leads us to conclude that we need  $0<|x|<min(δ,1|c|+1)$ I understand what you have done here clearly I think, but I'm not sure how I could have known to choose such an x as you did here

Comment: Note that the definition of continuity says: FOR ALL $\epsilon > 0$ THERE EXISTS $\delta > 0$ such that FOR ALL $x$ with $|x-x_0| < \delta$ it holds that $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$. When you negate this it becomes: THERE EXISTS $\epsilon > 0$ such that FOR ALL $\delta > 0$ THERE EXISTS $x$ with $|x - x_0| < \delta$ and $|f(x) - f(x_0)| \geq \epsilon$. Note that the hint above uses an arbitrary $\delta$ (since the negation tell you your solution must work for all $\delta > 0$) and gives you an outline of how to find some value $x$ with $|x-x_0| < \delta$ and $|f(x) - f(x_0)| \geq \epsilon$.

Comment: I chose $x$ by first playing around with the inequality: $$|f(x) - c| = \left| \frac{1- cx}{x}\right| \geq \frac{|1 - |c|\,|x|\,|}{|x|}$$ and then setting the right hand side equal to $1$ (note that $1$ was arbitrary; I could have set it equal to $5$ or $1/2$ since I could always find an $\epsilon$ less than my chosen number). The reason I chose the minimum with this and $\delta$ is because we also need to satisfy the condition $|x- 0| < \delta$ since $x_0 = 0$ in this case.

Comment: Ok that is very clear, I'll try with some other problems of my own now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since $1/x$ is continuous everywhere it's defined, we expect $f$ will be discontinuous at $0$. SO, suppose on contrary that $f$ is continuous at $0$. Then, we know that for all $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|x|<\delta\implies|c-f(x)|<\epsilon$. So, if we choose $\epsilon=1$, then there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|x|<\delta\implies|c-f(x)|<1$. Now since $1/x$ blows up at $0$, we can choose an $0<x_{0}<\delta$ such that $1/x_{0}>|c|+1$. Then, $|x_{0}|<\delta$, but $|c-f(x)|=|c-1/x_{0}|\geq 1/x_{0}-|c|>1\not<\epsilon$. This contradiction proves the desired discontinuity.

Answer (score 0):

We want to prove the discontinuity at $0$, i.e.
$$\exists\epsilon>0,\forall\delta>0,\exists x\in[-\delta,\delta]\setminus\{0\},\left|\frac1x-c\right|\ge\epsilon.$$
For this, any $\epsilon>0$ will do, as it is then sufficient, for every $\delta>0$, to find some $x\in(0,\delta]$ such that $\frac1x\ge|c|+\epsilon$, i.e. such that $x\le\frac1{|c|+\epsilon}$, and there are many such $x$s: the whole interval $\left(0,\min\left(\delta,\frac1{|c|+\epsilon}\right)\right]$.