# Find the set of real numbers where $f(x)$ is continuous.

Tags: analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta, piecewise-continuity

The function is defined  as

- $f(x) = x+\sqrt{2}$ if $x$ is rational
- $f(x) = x-3$ if $x$ is irrational

The question:
Find the set of real numbers at which $f$ is continuous.

Note : It presumably wants me to justify it with an epsilon-delta proof.

Any advice would be appreciated, I can't quite see how to proceed.

EDIT: For anyone looking for help on similar problems, try here -->

[Proving Discontinuity using Epsilon Delta for Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1906260/proving-discontinuity-using-epsilon-delta-for-function)

I eventually found it after further hunting, and it provides a greater degree of mathematical instruction than the answers given here.

Comment: Draw the graphs of $y=x+\sqrt2$ and $y=x-3$. Is there *any* value of $x$ at which they are close to each other? Take $\epsilon=1$, say, at any $x$; is there any $\delta$ small enough to ‘work’?

Comment: They, uh... don't look too close to each other. Those graphs are parallel. Am I missing something here?

Comment: They are indeed parallel, at a vertical distance of $3+\sqrt2$. So if you take $\epsilon=1$ and $a\in\Bbb R$, is there any $\delta$ that guarantees that $|f(x)-f(a)|<1$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta$?

Answer (score 1):

With sequences the problem is easy to solve: let $x_0 \in \mathbb R$.

Take a sequence $(a_n) $ in $\mathbb Q$ with $a_n \to x_0$. Then

$f(a_n)=a_n + \sqrt{2} \to x_0+\sqrt{2}$.

Next, take a sequence $(b_n) $ in $\mathbb R \setminus\mathbb Q$ with $b_n \to x_0$. Then

$f(b_n)=b_n -3\to x_0-3$.

Now suppose that $f$ is continuous in $x_0$. Then we would have

$\lim_{n \to \infty}f(a_n)=\lim_{n \to \infty}f(b_n)$, hence $x_0+\sqrt{2}=x_0-3$, a contradiction.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the input! So you think this is a trick question, and I need to justify that the set of real numbers at which f is continuous is empty?

Comment: ???? I have showed that there is no $x_0$ such that $f$ is  continuous in $x_0$. What is your problem ?

Comment: @Jo: No, it is not a trick question. You have to *prove* that for each $a\in\Bbb R$, $f$ is not continuous at $a$.

Comment: I understand that. I mentioned a 'trick', in that the question leads that there is such a set of x values at which f(x) is continuous.

Comment: Look, I appreciate help but please don't get so hung up on a turn of phrase and throw yourself into a lecture. It's not constructive, just condescending.

Comment: In my book, a question stated in such a way as to misdirect (as this one does) is a trick question. There's nothing wrong with that, nor do I think it is an improper question. It's just deliberately misleading, and I spent a while confused because the function appeared discontinuous yet demanded of me the points of continuity.